# Find all matches in a List LinQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

Given the situation I got a string array from a file containing IDs.
Which may be separated by various characters, " " : ; etc.
I would like to obtain every string in one new list/array, using LinQ, that contained any of the given separators.
I am currently doing this in a rather inconvenient way

```
string[] separator = { " ", ",", ";", ".", ":", "/" };
string[] arr = { };
listExceptions = someSource;
List<string> entrysWithSeparator=
(from s in listExceptions where (ContainsAny(s,separator) == true) select s).ToList(); 
//ContainsAny returns a bool, if any of the separators was found in the string
List<string> tmpExceptions = listExceptions.ToList();

foreach (string s in entrysWithSeparator)
{                
    arr = s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    tmpExceptions.AddRange(arr.ToList());
}
listExceptions = new string[listExceptions.Count()-1];
listExceptions = tmpExceptions.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Why are you creating an array in the penultimate line, only to overwrite the value of the variable in the last line? I'm finding it hard to follow what you're trying to achieve - a concrete example would be useful.

Comment: How about showing the possible input data vs. what is expected

Comment: @JonSkeet I assume you are refering to the last two line.
I had some problems not overwriting the existing array with a new one where there were some artifacts left, I didnt had any clue how to properly solve that without creating a fresh array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to combine the query and the loop by using `SelectMany`:

```
listExceptions = listExceptions
    .Where(s => ContainsAny(s,separator))
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToArray();
```

I assume that you are using `ContainsAny` method [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519555/335858) in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.SelectMany(s => 
                s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
             .Distinct();
```

There is no need for ContainsAny since Split() on a string containing no seperators also returns the string itself.