# vb.net How to check if a string contains one of the values of a key of Dictionary (or array)

Tags: vb.net

I need to check if a string contains one of the values (strings) of an Hashset

I was able to do it, but I've searched for a faster code. I found solutions only for c#, java, phyton but nothing for vb.net

This is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
    Dim mDict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim ArrStr() As String = {"First:", "Second:", "Third:"}
    Dim StringA$ = "Second: It works!"

For Each k As String In ArrStr
    If StringA.Contains(k) Then
        mDict(k) = StringA
        Exit For
    End If
Next k
```

My question is: is there a way to avoid loop?

EDIT:

I want to thank you all for giving me suggestions and clarifications.
I've understood that my question doesn't have answer and maybe it is a bad question.

I haven't got an answer but I've learned something ... Thanks again

Comment: If you found a C# solution that does what you want, it should be fairly trivial to translate it into VB.NET.

Comment: @Cortright I was not able to do that, I've tryed but... nothing

Comment: Post the C# equivalent.

Comment: @Cortright This is the link to the question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519539/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-of-some-strings)

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid loop"? Any solution will have to loop, in your code or in the api.

Comment: @genespos - VB.NET translation of code in the link:  `If (s.Contains("a") OrElse s.Contains("b") OrElse s.Contains("c")) Then` - but as others have pointed out, you'll still have loops.

Comment: @the_lotus I've thought that an api would be faster, isn't it?

Comment: I am curious. Why you do not want use loop?

Comment: Yeah - you might be able to avoid writing a loop in your own code, but it will still be looping in the API to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ, but it will still perform a loop internally:

```
mDict = ArrStr.Where(Function(x) StringA.Contains(x))
              .ToDictionary(Function(x) x, Function(x) StringA)
```

Comment: I've never used linq. Do you think it will be faster?

Comment: No. It will take at least the same amount of time, most likely a bit more, because of delegate invocation and such, but it should be unnoticeable difference.