# Search for paragraph for sentence with variables

Tags: c#, regex, search

I am using C# to search a paragraph and see if it contains a sentence like this: "... ... The amount $5,234.12 does not match our record. Please ... ..."

What I am interested is the sentence "The amount [whatever] does not match our record." However, how do I make the dollar amount a wildcard? I don't really care what the dollar amount is, I just want to check this sentence pattern exists in the paragraph.

Should I use RegEx? How? I would hate to just search for "The amount", and then followed by "does not match our record". Feel like there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: If you care about order maybe regex or you can check if your string contains 2 strings, the first and the second part of the sentence ignoring the amount. Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519539/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-of-some-strings. Just to specify, in the link above the condition is if string contains any, in your case you would need to check if string contains both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplest regex** for this:

`The amount .+ does not match our record`.

The problem with the above is that `.+` might match anything, including false positive, for instance "*The amount*", followed by a lot of words, and then an unrelated "*does not match our record*".

If such edge case could happen, you can use some more restrictions on the regex : limit number of characters and/or restrain the possible characters :

**Limit number of characters** : the 'amount' is between 2 characters ($1) and, let's say, 20 characters:

`The amount .{2,20} does not match our record`

**Limit possible characters** if you want to make sure the amount pattern contains only digits, dollar sign, dot and comma:

`The amount [0-9$,.]+ does not match our record`

You can also mix both :

`The amount [0-9$,.]{2,20} does not match our record`

[Test it online on RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=The+amount+%5b0-9%24%2c.%5d%7b2%2c20%7d+does+not+match+our+record&i=...+...+The+amount+%245%2c234.12+does+not+match+our+record.+Please+...+...%0d%0a)

Comment: side note : it may be also better on a performance point of view to restrict the regex, that would prevent useless _backtrackings_