# Python: How to check a string for substrings from a list?

Tags: python, string, list, substring

How can I check a string for substrings contained in a list, like in [Check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925), but in Python?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Try this test:

```
any(substring in string for substring in substring_list)
```

It will return `True` if any of the substrings in `substring_list` is contained in `string`.

Note that there is a Python analogue of [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925/to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-of-strings-is-there-a-b/500930#500930) in the linked question:

```
from itertools import imap
any(imap(string.__contains__, substring_list))
```

In Python 3, you can use `map` directly instead:

```
any(map(string.__contains__, substring_list))
```

Probably the above version using a generator expression is more clear though.

Comment: @newtover: [Generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) don't have square brackets.

Comment: is  there any way to get the substring when it will return True?

Comment: @vagabond You can use `next(substring for substring in substring_list if substring in string)`, which will return the first matching substring, or throw `StopIteration` if there is no match.  Or use a simple loop: `for substring in substring_list: if substring in string: return substring`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach variable 'substring''s lifetime is DONE and unavailable in the StopIteration exception