# How to check if a string contains any element of a List<string>?

Tags: c#, string, list, contains

I have an if statement, where I would like to check, if a string contains any item of a `list<string>`.

```
if (str.Contains(list2.Any()) && str.Contains(ddl_language.SelectedValue))
{
    lstpdfList.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The correct formulation is

```
list2.Any(s => str.Contains(s))
```

This is read as "does `list2` include any string `s` such that `str` contains `s`?".

Comment: And in case, if a dropdown list's selected value equal with an item from the list , how the formulation would be ?

Comment: @user1597284: If `selectedValue` is a `string` then `list2.Contains(selectedValue)`. Take a look at the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class and all the extension methods it provides.

Comment: Is there any way to get the value of 's' after finding that 'str' contains 's'?

Comment: @T-Dog sure but you have to specify it better. Like what happens if there are multiple `s`s from the list contained inside `str`?

Comment: For example, if you replace `Any` with `FirstOrDefault`, the return value is going to be the first `s` that is contained in `str` or `null` if no such string exists in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
if (myList.Any(x => mystring.Contains(x)))
    // ....
```

Comment: And in case, if a dropdown list's selected value equal with an item from the list , how the formulation would be ?