# Find all articles that contain words with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

trying to learn Linq but bumping against a wall here.

Im trying to find all articles that contain multiple strings, but not sure how to use the .Contains when passing in a List.

```
private void SearchArticles()
{
    AdminEntities db = new AdminEntities();

    var searchStrs = new List<string> {"search_string1", "search_string2"};
    var artListfull = db.view_M02Articles_SearchPublished(0, "").ToList();
    var artList = artListfull.FindAll(n => n.Bodytext.Contains(searchStrs));

    Label1.Text = artList.Count.ToString();
    Repeater1.DataSource = artList;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

what wold be the correct syntax here?

Comment: When you say "articles that contain multiple strings", do you mean all of the strings? Or just more than one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings) - Is there a better way to write this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925/to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-of-strings-is-there-a-b)

Comment: I need all strings to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Edit]** Supposing that `BodyText` is of type `string`

you can try this:

```
//the article body must contain "ALL" the search terms
var artList = artListfull.Where(art => searchStrs.All(art.BodyText.Contains));
```

or

```
//the article body must contain "At least one" of the search terms
var artList = artListfull.Where(art => searchStrs.Any(art.BodyText.Contains));
```

**[Edit 2]** replacing `str => art.BodyText.Contains(str)` by `art.BodyText.Contains`

Comment: This will work although it will be inefficiently iterating over the body text multiple times

Comment: Note that you can replace `str => art.BodyText.Contains(str)` with just `art.BodyText.Contains`

Comment: @AlexG : I don't think there is another alternative than iterating through both 'search items' and 'body text', it's like a 'join'

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ

```
var artList= (from art in artFullList
              from search in searchStrs 
              where art.Bodytext.Contains(search)
              select art).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var artList = artListfull.Where(a => searchStrs.Any(s => a.Bodytext.Contains(s)))
                         .ToList();
```