# Duplicate users added to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to add a new value to my database. `UserPassword` and `RePassword` must have the same value and a user with `UserName` must not already exist in the database.

```
  public User NewUser(int HotelID, string UserName, string UserPassword, string RePassword, string FullName, string Email, bool Active, bool MasterUser)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.HotelID = HotelID;
        user.UserName = UserName;
        user.UserPassword = UserPassword;
        user.FullName = FullName;
        user.Email = Email;
        user.IsActiveq = Active;
        user.IsMaster = MasterUser;

        var cekUser = (from c in _UserRepository.All()
                       where c.HotelID == HotelID
                       select c.UserName).ToList();
        if (UserPassword == RePassword)
        {
            foreach (string cek in cekUser)
            {
                var x = cek;
                if (UserName != x)
                {
                    _UserRepository.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }

        _UserRepository.CommitChanges();

        return user;

    }
```

Every time I run my code a new line is added to the database, although a user with the supplied user name already exists in the database.

Why does this happen? Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: What is that loop intended to do?  It looks like you are adding the new user to your repository as many times as you have users.

Comment: i try to check, are my value exist in database or not with the loop

Comment: It looks like every time the `UserName` doesn't match `x`, you're adding the user to your database. Why not just check your list of strings for the `string` value? `bool ListContainsString = listOfStrings.Any(myString.Contains);'.

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: Check this thread, it's a very well known use case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925/to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-of-strings-is-there-a-b

Comment: @noviankristianto You should validate all these using `ViewModels` and not in the code. You can do validations using `Data Annotations` on `ViewModels`

Comment: how about making username field unique in your database?

Comment: my username unique with HotelID. in every HotelId, like 2, username can have same value, but if HotelID is  different, username can have same value

Comment: Say you get a, b, c in the same hotel. And your new user is b. In your loop, a != b, add b; c != b, add b.

Comment: TIP: Your `NewUser` method should accept a user object rather than build it within. It's a good practice to separate concerns that way. `public User NewUser(User user){...}`

Answer (score 4):

I think your code should be something like this:

```
if (UserPassword == RePassword)
{
    // Also I thinks you should finish whether user existed logic in database
    // but for now, let's follow your original logic
    var existedUsers = (from c in _UserRepository.All()
                       where c.HotelID == HotelID
                       select c.UserName).ToList();

    if (!existedUsers.Any(u => u == UserName))
    {
        _UserRepository.Add(user);
        _UserRepository.CommitChanges();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your logic wrong. If there is more than one user in a given hotel, your code will be adding more users for all users with names different from UserName.

```
bool found = false;
foreach(string cek in cekUser)
{
  if ( UserName == cek)
  {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!found)
   _UserRepository.Add(user);
```

Comment: can you explain to me, what logic should i use

Answer (score 0):

Just offering an alternate idea.

If you have access to the database, the best approach will be to make the `Username` field UNIQUE. That way, even if you get your code wrong, a duplicate insert will fail. Then you capture that fail gracefully in your Repository, and Bob's your uncle.