# Winforms check if string starts with but in multiple values

Tags: c#

I use this code to check if string starts with **34CDB**:

```
string word = "34CDBXXXX";

if (word.StartsWith("34CDB")) 
{
   // do something 
}
```

I want many values, not just **34CDB**. I try to change it to

```
if (word.StartsWith("34CDB", "AT4X3", "3AXP3"))
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: Question is extremely unclear. What is `stringArray` and how you are going to use it? What have you tried? How do you know that **nothing works**? Errors?

Comment: You tried lots of code, but nothing works. Could you post some of that code?

Comment: @user2651946 `columnChars` is an array of `char`. Is `34CDB` valid value for `char`?

Comment: `new char[] { '34CDB', 'E808' }` won't compile and `E808` are 4 characters, not 5. Please show some valid and invalid input/output pairs.

Comment: `if (txtBox.Text.Length >= 5){var txt = txtBox.Text.Substring(0, 5); }` and then match against the per-defined values!!!

Comment: Your code won't even compile, make it an array of `string`. Then add following method: `public bool StartsWithColumn(string toCheck, string[] columnChars) { return columnChars.Any(x => toCheck.StartsWith(x)); }`.

Comment: See [To check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings) - Is there a better way to write this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925/to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-of-strings-is-there-a-b) and replace `Contains` with `StartsWith`.

Comment: @user2651946 now your question is clear, but its closed and should be reopened for answering. Next time please please provide better context  and description of your problem, and it will be answered quickly without being closed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to check if the user entered one of your strings:

```
bool enteredAny = stringArray.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim());
```