# How to check if a string variable contains a substring of a string element from an array - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, substring

If I have a string array:

```
public string[] foo = {... , "ABC123", ...};
```

and a variable:

```
string bar = "ABC123DEF456";
```

how can I check if bar contains `"ABC123"`?

At the moment, I'm doing:

```
if (Array.Exists(foo, element => element == bar))
```

to check if the entire string bar exists in foo, but I want know if an element in foo is a substring of bar. How would I do this? Is it possible to use `.Contains`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925/check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting it into words - you want to know if any of the items in `foo` is contained in `bar`. So in code, almost exactly the same:

```
if(foo.Any(item => bar.Contains(item)))
```

Comment: Quick and simple response. Thanks!