# How to find multiple text direct without loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a list -> 12,15,16,19,10,11,13  various text in this list (2000+) now i want to find it my.txt file in this list  using one cmd  without loop or for each..anyone have solution this?

Sample code -

```
dim x as string = io.file.readalltext("myfile.txt")
```

Button 1 click...

```
Dim result as string = x.index of (item1,item2)
```

Comment: It's probably difficult to understand what objects you're managing. Could you post a sample of your code and the input? Maybe also something you have already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Question unclear, please paraphrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find list of string using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891939/how-to-find-list-of-string-using-vb-net)

Comment: dim x as string=io.file.readalltext("myfile.txt")  - dim result as string =  x.index of("12,123,12345")

Comment: You could do this with one line of code with Linq but, guess what, there is a loop behind the scenes with the Linq.