# How do i make .Any with combination of .Contains non-case sensitive

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
query = query.Where(x => words.Any(x.Message.Contains));
```

`words` is a `string[]` and `x.Message` is a `string`

I would like to filter out my query based on all the words in my array but I would like this not to be case sensitive comparison so if i type 'bob' or 'BOb' it should not care and still compare those words against the message if Message is 'BOB is awesome' or 'bob is awesome'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better option is to use `Contains` overload with `StringComparison` parameter:

```
query = query.Where(x => words.Any(s => x.Message
    .Contains(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Recommended is `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 1):

This will compare the list of strings to the message as you desire. I use `.ToLower()` to convert both the string and each word in the list so it's essentially case-insensitive.

```
query = query.Where(x => words.Any(s => x.Message.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower())));
```

Check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings): [Check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500925/check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-of-strings)